# Is WordPress appropriate for building customized Web Apps

Tags: wordpress, web-applications

Our company is aiming to build an **eLearning Website**, we are a team of developers and our boss is suggesting using **WordPress** for it. We are experienced in building web apps using Codeigniter and Laravel.

I already know that we can build any type of web app using WordPress, but my questions is that is it appropriate using WordPress for building it, in terms of ease in teamwork, time, customization, easiness or anything else which you may suggest compared to usign Codeigniter or Laravel?

Comment: I have been developing in WordPress for years. It can do almost anything you need it to. But something to remember is that it's **still primarily a blogging platform**. This often makes it a pain to work with. My advice: if you know Laravel, I'd shy away from using WordPress.

Comment: I'll second @rnevius on "still primarily a blogging platform".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes definitely Wordpress would be a great platform to work in. Since it has extended its wings from a normal CMS to ecommerce, social networking and much more to come.

And about developing the eLearning site yes it would be definitely magnificent to develop it in wordpress as there could be some plugins for it or else you can develop one with ease.

Benefits of Working in Wordpress:

1. Large number of community members around to help you.
2. Your website will be most search engine friendly with it.
3. Really takes less time to develop any application because most of things are in built and you can also modify them to match your requirements.
4. Installation and migration is effortless.

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely is suitable. There's several advantages:

- Prototype can be developed in a number of days
- Great for SEO since it's also a blogging platform. You won't have to code SEO friendly CMS by hand.
- Possible to have a website front end that can compliment the webapp front end
- JSON API is already done for you.
- Lots of people are proficient with wordpress so it's not difficult to find staff further down the track
- It can use a responsive design straight out the box
- The JSON API can work with HTML5 mobile app API's like cordova and jquerymobile and onsen.